# How to send a hash of properties via URL param

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, hash

In rails, I want to accept a hash of properties as a single parameter in a URL. However, I can't figure out how to even send a hash of properties to test out my code. It would be awesome if I can just pass a JSON string as a parameter...but not sure how to do that.

Something like:

website.com/?properties=properties

with properties = {\"color\":\"black\",\"type\":\"stylist\"}

Comment: What about encoding JSON in base64?  However, a better approach would be to send plain JSON via a POST request.

Comment: interesting...i tried that but keep getting a bad URI error:
api_add_customer?token=D2rKZW3u5RJqfNJv-8kUDOfj5llI-fRw&first_name=ptest&last_name=ptest2&phone_number=3109952448&properties=eyJjb2xvciI6ImJsYWNrIiwidHlwZSI6InN0eWxpc3QifQ==\n

gives me ERROR bad URI `/api_add_customer?token=D2rKZW3u5RJqfNJv-8kUDOfj5llI-fRw&first_name=ptest&last_name=ptest2&phone_number=3109952448&properties=eyJjb2xvciI6ImJsYWNrIiwidHlwZSI6InN0eWxpc3QifQ==\\n'.

Comment: Make sure you're encoding it in to a base64 encoding that is url safe (i.e. `urlsafe_decode64(str)` and `urlsafe_encode64(bin)` ~> http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/base64/rdoc/Base64.html)

Comment: @RobertoReale you should put your suggestion as an answer, that worked:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aa better approach would be to send plain JSON via a POST request.

However, if you absolutely want to use GET, it is possibile to send up a JSON by encoding it in **base64**.  Make sure to use **url safe encoding**, though, as provided by the methods `urlsafe_decode64()` `urlsafe_encode64()`.